# What is the best way to wrap a function with generic type retaining in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

As the code shows, I want to wrap the first function to the second one, yes I can make it by the `wrappedFunc`. But is there more elegant way? For example, can I don't bother to write `<T, K>` again in the second function?

```
const func = <T, K>(a: T, b: object) => {
  // ...
};

const wrappedFunc = <T, K>(a: T, b: object) => {
  return func(a, {name: 'john', ...b});
  // ...
};
```

Comment: `T` will be inferred the same, but what is `K` used for here?

Comment: Please add more context to your question. A description of ```K``` helps and any other specific info that can help answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
type FuncType = <T, K>(a: T, b: object);

function func(fn:FuncType) => {
  // ...
};

function wrappedFunc(fn:FuncType) => {
  return func(a, {name: 'john', ...b});
  // ...
};
```

Why not just extract the entire type into a common type and use it for both functions ?

Comment: Did you mean to make `func` and `wrappedFunc` have the type of `FuncType`? That would be closer to the question code. What you have is different.

Comment: It'd be slightly better, since you've extracted the common type governing both functions into 1 place @ConnorLow